# JSON.NET is throwing 'additional text found in JSON string after finishing deserializing object."

Tags: javascript, c#, json, json.net

I have a Javascript control that returns JSON string as an AJAX to the server. But when I try to save, Newtonsoft is throwing the exception

> Additional text found in JSON string after finishing deserializing object.

I tried building a very simple JSON as below which threw this exception

```
[{
    "TopicName": "Hello World",
    "OrdinalOrder": 0
}, {
    "TopicName": "Hello World",
    "OrdinalOrder": 0
}, {
    "TopicName": "Hello World",
    "OrdinalOrder": 0
}, {
    "TopicName": "Hello World",
    "OrdinalOrder": 0
}, {
    "TopicName": "Hello World",
    "OrdinalOrder": 0
}, {
    "TopicName": "Hello World",
    "OrdinalOrder": 0
}, {
    "TopicName": "Hello World",
    "OrdinalOrder": 0
}, {
    "TopicName": "Hello World",
    "OrdinalOrder": 0
}, {
    "TopicName": "Hello World",
    "OrdinalOrder": 0
}, {
    "TopicName": "Hello World",
    "OrdinalOrder": 0
}, {
    "TopicName": "Hello World",
    "OrdinalOrder": 0
}, {
    "TopicName": "Hello World",
    "OrdinalOrder": 0
}, {
    "TopicName": "Hello World",
    "OrdinalOrder": 0
}, {
    "TopicName": "Hello World",
    "OrdinalOrder": 0
}, {
    "TopicName": "Hello World",
    "OrdinalOrder": 0
}, {
    "TopicName": "Hello World",
    "OrdinalOrder": 0
}, {
    "TopicName": "Hello World",
    "OrdinalOrder": 0
}, {
    "TopicName": "Hello World",
    "OrdinalOrder": 0
}, {
    "TopicName": "Hello World",
    "OrdinalOrder": 0
}, {
    "TopicName": "Hello World",
    "OrdinalOrder": 0
}, {
    "TopicName": "Hello World",
    "OrdinalOrder": 0
}, {
    "TopicName": "Hello World",
    "OrdinalOrder": 0
}, {
    "TopicName": "Hello World",
    "OrdinalOrder": 0
}, {
    "TopicName": "Hello World",
    "OrdinalOrder": 0
}, {
    "TopicName": "Hello World",
    "OrdinalOrder": 0
}, {
    "TopicName": "Hello World",
    "OrdinalOrder": 0
}, {
    "TopicName": "Hello World",
    "OrdinalOrder": 0
}, {
    "TopicName": "Hello World",
    "OrdinalOrder": 0
}, {
    "TopicName": "Hello World",
    "OrdinalOrder": 0
}, {
    "TopicName": "Hello World",
    "OrdinalOrder": 0
}, {
    "TopicName": "Hello World",
    "OrdinalOrder": 0
}, {
    "TopicName": "Hello World",
    "OrdinalOrder": 0
}, {
    "TopicName": "Hello World",
    "OrdinalOrder": 0
}, {
    "TopicName": "Hello World",
    "OrdinalOrder": 0
}, {
    "TopicName": "Hello World",
    "OrdinalOrder": 0
}, {
    "TopicName": "Hello World",
    "OrdinalOrder": 0
}, {
    "TopicName": "Hello World",
    "OrdinalOrder": 0
}, {
    "TopicName": "Hello World",
    "OrdinalOrder": 0
}, {
    "TopicName": "Hello World",
    "OrdinalOrder": 0
}, {
    "TopicName": "Hello World",
    "OrdinalOrder": 0
}, {
    "TopicName": "Hello World",
    "OrdinalOrder": 0
}, {
    "TopicName": "Hello World",
    "OrdinalOrder": 0
}, {
    "TopicName": "Hello World",
    "OrdinalOrder": 0
}, {
    "TopicName": "Hello World",
    "OrdinalOrder": 0
}, {
    "TopicName": "Hello World",
    "OrdinalOrder": 0
}, {
    "TopicName": "Hello World",
    "OrdinalOrder": 0
}, {
    "TopicName": "Hello World",
    "OrdinalOrder": 0
}, {
    "TopicName": "Hello World",
    "OrdinalOrder": 0
}, {
    "TopicName": "Hello World",
    "OrdinalOrder": 0
}, {
    "TopicName": "Hello World",
    "OrdinalOrder": 0
}, {
    "TopicName": "Hello World",
    "OrdinalOrder": 0
}, {
    "TopicName": "Hello World",
    "OrdinalOrder": 0
}, {
    "TopicName": "Hello World",
    "OrdinalOrder": 0
}, {
    "TopicName": "Hello World",
    "OrdinalOrder": 0
}, {
    "TopicName": "Hello World",
    "OrdinalOrder": 0
}, {
    "TopicName": "Hello World",
    "OrdinalOrder": 0
}, {
    "TopicName": "Hello World",
    "OrdinalOrder": 0
}, {
    "TopicName": "Hello World",
    "OrdinalOrder": 0
}, {
    "TopicName": "Hello World",
    "OrdinalOrder": 0
}, {
    "TopicName": "Hello World",
    "OrdinalOrder": 0
}, {
    "TopicName": "Hello World",
    "OrdinalOrder": 0
}, {
    "TopicName": "Hello World",
    "OrdinalOrder": 0
}, {
    "TopicName": "Hello World",
    "OrdinalOrder": 0
}, {
    "TopicName": "Hello World",
    "OrdinalOrder": 0
}, {
    "TopicName": "Hello World",
    "OrdinalOrder": 0
}, {
    "TopicName": "Hello World",
    "OrdinalOrder": 0
}, {
    "TopicName": "Hello World",
    "OrdinalOrder": 0
}, {
    "TopicName": "Hello World",
    "OrdinalOrder": 0
}, {
    "TopicName": "Hello World",
    "OrdinalOrder": 0
}, {
    "TopicName": "Hello World",
    "OrdinalOrder": 0
}, {
    "TopicName": "Hello World",
    "OrdinalOrder": 0
}, {
    "TopicName": "Hello World",
    "OrdinalOrder": 0
}, {
    "TopicName": "Hello World",
    "OrdinalOrder": 0
}, {
    "TopicName": "Hello World",
    "OrdinalOrder": 0
}, {
    "TopicName": "Hello World",
    "OrdinalOrder": 0
}, {
    "TopicName": "Hello World",
    "OrdinalOrder": 0
}, {
    "TopicName": "Hello World",
    "OrdinalOrder": 0
}, {
    "TopicName": "Hello World",
    "OrdinalOrder": 0
}, {
    "TopicName": "Hello World",
    "OrdinalOrder": 0
}, {
    "TopicName": "Hello World",
    "OrdinalOrder": 0
}, {
    "TopicName": "Hello World",
    "OrdinalOrder": 0
}, {
    "TopicName": "Hello World",
    "OrdinalOrder": 0
}, {
    "TopicName": "Hello World",
    "OrdinalOrder": 0
}, {
    "TopicName": "Hello World",
    "OrdinalOrder": 0
}, {
    "TopicName": "Hello World",
    "OrdinalOrder": 0
}]
```

And the API I am invoking is

```
DataSet dsTopics = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataSet>(strTopicset);
```

where strTopicSet contains the above string. And when I paste the above string in http://www.jsonlint.com/ it says Valid JSON.

Can some one guide me where I am going wrong. I did go through StackExchange forums on Newtonsoft and the typical error but could not zero in on the exact cause of this.

I am using 9.0.1.19813 version of Newtonsoft.

Comment: Can you show the relevant code in question.

Answer (score 8):

json format is not look like dataset format.

try this.

```
DataTable dsTopics = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(strTopicset);
```

OR: (I think this is more useful)

```
public class Topic
{
    public string TopicName { get; set; }
    public int OrdinalOrder { get; set; }
}

List<Topic> topics = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Topic>>(strTopicset);
```

Comment: I agree with levent, using a List is much simpler unless you absolutely require a DataSet for some reason.

Answer (score 3):

Your JSON does not represent a valid `DataSet`. Based on the example you've given it should look like this:

```
{ 
    "Topics": 
        [{"TopicName":"Hello World","OrdinalOrder":0},
         {"TopicName":"Hello World","OrdinalOrder":0},
         {"TopicName":"Hello World","OrdinalOrder":0},
         ... etc etc more rows ...
         {"TopicName":"Hello World","OrdinalOrder":0},
         {"TopicName":"Hello World","OrdinalOrder":0}]
}
```

This JSON would represent a `DataSet` containing a single `DataTable` named "Topics" with two columns named "TopicName" and "OrdinalOrder" respectively.